# Varnish causing timeout on Drupal feeds import

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, timeout, varnish, drupal-feeds

I'm running Drupal 7 with Varnish. The site in question is actually bypassing Varnish in the vcl file.

Anyway, I'm getting the ajax error when I try to run a feeds import. I had this problem before but got rid of it by upping the fast CGI timeout.

This time I've had to disable varnish to run the import - which completely solves the problem.

Question is, where's the timeout on Varnish. I've disabled or upped anything that looks like a timeout but it's still timing out around 60-120 seconds (sorry haven't timed it exactly).

Any suggestions that mean I don't have to take down Varnish everytime I run a feed import would be great!

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but probably the import will use something like a stream upload. I don't have any experience with this kind of situation yet, but i could imagine a `pipe` (instead of a pass) will solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks @Arjan - I'm actually bypassing this site using a pipe already - I guess trying it as a pass would be the next step...